# HybridAuth/Laravel - How to implement without a constructor?

Tags: php, class, laravel, controller, hybridauth

I'm using a laravel 4 script, which has already a UserController.
I tried to make a new controller for the HybridAuth, but then methods can't be found (I have to use some functions from UserController).
On the other hand, if i implement it in the existed UserController i can't use 2 constructors. I'm new to this stuff, please guide me!

**SteamController.php** (the new controller)

```
class SteamController extends UserController {

    public function __construct(Hybrid_Auth $hybridAuth)
    {
        $this->hybridAuth = $hybridAuth;
    }

    public function login($action='') {
    ...
    }
...
```

**UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends BaseController{

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Can you use hybridAuth from SteamController.php ?

Comment: @vps It works till the part i get my steam account, then i need to create the new user in the database so i have to call some methods from UserController which i can't (I get Controller method not found).

Comment: what function do you want to use from usercontroller? Why don't you extend userController class?

Comment: @vps For example this one: $username = $this->create_username_if_exists($openid_username);
I've tried class SteamController extends UserController but it still can't find the method.